# Short Circuit Variable Assignment at least one varible is known to be defined

Tags: typescript

I have some code here involving short circuit assignment:

```
// varibleA: object | undefined   
// varibleB: object | undefined   
if(varibleA || varibleB){   
   const selectedVarible: object = varibleA || varibleB;   
 //ERROR Type "object | undefined is not assignable to type object.   
}
```

This seems to me that if either varA or varB is defined, then the short circuit assignment should always return a defined object. This might be because the short circuit asignment handles this like an else and will always at least assign the second varible (B), which has type object | undefined. If this is the case how do I get around this? Thank you

Comment: I could split this to two if's but it seems like I shouldn't have to duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's control flow analysis works better with variables (or properties of variables) and not with general expressions.  That means you could *first* store `varibleA || varibleB` into its own variable, and *then* check it:

```
// varibleA: object | undefined   
// varibleB: object | undefined   
const selectedVariable = varibleA || varibleB; // still object | undefined
if (selectedVariable) {
  // now selectedVariable is known to be object
  console.log(selectedVariable.toString()); // no error
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!